# Edge_size not working with ggVennDiagram on only one computer

Tags: r, venn-diagram

We are attempting to use `ggVennDiagram` to plot a few Venn diagrams for a research project, and the simple code I wrote works on my MacBook laptop and my Acer PC, but not on my ASUS laptop (using windows). The code does not return any errors, but does not accurately reflect the `edge_size` argument. Basically, the edge size will not change regardless of what is entered and I am wondering if anyone has any idea what to do to get it to work on the ASUS laptop. RStudio was updated to the newest version before we tried running the code. I have attached the lines of code for the Venn below,  note it also utilizes the tidyverse package.

```
p<- ggVennDiagram(lapply(Data[2:5], function(x) which(x==1)), label="count",edge_lty= "solid", edge_size = 2)
p + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Blues", direction = 1)
```

Things we've tried:

Tried changing edge size to 0, 1, 2, 10, 100, 20, etc..  but the edge size would not change when attempting it on the ASUS laptop, the Venn would still work and no errors were returned.

Tried the code on a MacBook and acer PC and it worked properly (edge size changes when code is used on same version of RStudio on PC and Mac), just wouldn't work on a ASUS laptop.

Comment: Can you please include a fully reproducible example with data and all code so we can reproduce the problem? Also, the list of all the installed package versions on both systems. Are you sure they're the same versions? Have you tried restarting R from a clean environment with only the minimal packages attached?

Comment: Yes is seems like you may have a conflicting package or something loaded on that specific computer